# Обводка рамкой заданного div после скролла страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день. Есть скрипт плавной промотки страницы до заданного id div'a. Как сделать так, чтобы в конце промотки заданный div подсвечивался на несколько секунд рамкой. Подскажите пожалуйста решение.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var target = this.hash;
                var $target = $(target);

          $('html, body').animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
          }, 1000, 'swing');
          });
        });
```

Comment: У `animate` есть callback для того момента, когда анимация закончилась. Там можете с помощью второго `animate` и `css` добавить+убрать рамку.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста подробнее куда что дописывать, а то я в java ни бум бум. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

День добрый! В .animate() четвертым параметром можно указать функцию, которая будет выполняться после выполнения анимации.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var target = this.hash;
            var $target = $(target);

      $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
      }, 1000, 'swing', function() {
           $('.div').css('border', '1px solid red'); // изменение бордера дива с классом div
         });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, решил вместо рамки поставить .animate opacity